# Launching app in landscape only mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, orientation, landscape

I've written an app that supports only landscape mode. For some reason, it is being very stubborn. It launches and runs great on the simulator, but when I go to launch it on my device, it will not launch or rotate to landscape mode at all. **I'm running 5.1 on my iPad**, and using Xcode 4.6.2. Here is everything I've tried after searching on this site for a solution:

1. Edited my `-info.plist` and deleted support for portrait mode in the supported orientation interface options
2. In the projects target, in the supported interface orientations I highlighted only landscape left and right

3  Added:

```
(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {     
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

To my only ViewController file. It runs in landscape only on the simulator, but is being very difficult on my device. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The method you added is only for iOS 5 or earlier. iOS 6 uses a complete different method. See the docs for `UIViewController` for details.

Comment: I'm testing it on a device running iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html), it describes the opposite of your problem but the resolution is the same.

Comment: I'm still very new to Objective-C, I read through it and am trying some of it but it goes way over my head.

Comment: Could you help me out with what the resolution is?

Comment: Go through each method described in the top half of the document and implement it. You should consider all methods, both iOS 5 and 6. If the app only supports landscape the implementation should be quite obvious as each method can only return a couple of values.

Comment: I've implemented everything, for some reason it still won't work.

Comment: Have you added breakpoints to check which ones are being called at runtime?